# How can I pop up activity when alarm goes off?

Tags: java, android

In my Broadcaster Receiver,

I have this set:

```
//Intent that enables the view to pop up when alarm goes off
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClassName("com.example.Device.MainActivity", "com.example.Device.OtherActivity");
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
```

and in my notification service, I have this:

```
// First let's define the intent to trigger when notification is selected
        // Start out by creating a normal intent (in this case to open an activity)
        intent = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
```

For some reason, when the notification goes off, the activity that I want to pop up does not pop up when alarm rings.

How can I pop up my activity when the alarm goes off/rings? I have done it before but I changed something in my code to mess it up.

Comment: Could you show your intent filter in your app manifest?

Comment: did you set "intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);" in your notification service?

Comment: Actually, nm, your intent is explicit, so the app being started doesn't need an intent-filter.

Comment: The documentation for setClassName(string, string) says public Intent setClassName (String packageName, String className). But it looks like you specified a className for both.

Comment: I fixed that and another thing and it seems to be working. Thank you!